# Why the var definition ends with () in this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, parentheses

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to understand why a variable declaration ends with "()": "var counter = ( ..... )();". If "()" are removed, it does not work but, what is their purpose? What do they tell JavaScript to do?

Se the code in this link.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/codeeditor?cid=oojs-64

Thanks!

Comment: `()` will execute a function. So, inside `( ..... )` you will have a function, it will be executed and `counter` would be the return value of said function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: because the function is an `Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)`

Comment: Relevant: [What is this JavaScript pattern called and why is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26092101) | [Why assign an IIFE to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26451697) | [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396) |

Comment: Ok, I see it. Thanks for pointing a newbie in the right direction. I have not seen this in my classes.